# Flex Charts -- How can I change the color of a chartItem on rollover?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, colors, series

Is there a way to set a rollover color for each series in a chart?

For instance, I have a column chart with two series: one series is set to blue and the second series is set to gold.

When the user mouses over the blue series, I would like the blue to turn to bright blue. And when the user mouses over the gold series, I would like the gold to turn to bright gold.

Also, is it possible to change the color of the chart item when a chart item is clicked?

Thanks,

Lacy

Answer (score 2):

[quietlyscheming](http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/charts/chart-sampler/) has a lot of excellent examples.  Basically you need to create your own itemRenderer for the series and trap the mouse moving over it and change states or colours at it does.  This is a very well documented path.

Comment: while the quietly scheming chart sampler looks dated ( 2006 ) its an excellent resource from the man who actually wrote the charting code!

Comment: If the main site is inaccessible, here's a [snapshot on the Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20080314012422/http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/charts/chart-sampler/).